# Kotlin Extension Methods in Freemarker Template

Tags: kotlin, freemarker, capitalization

Given the Freemarker template

```
class ${name.capitalize()}
```

and the data

```
val data = mapOf("name" to "test")
```

I'd like to get the following result by applying the extension method `capitalize()` on `name`:

```
class Test
```

However, an error is thrown:

```
FreeMarker template error:
For "." left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar):
==> name  [in template "table.ftl" at line 1, column 24]

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${name.capitalize()}  [in template "table.ftl" at line 1, column 22]
----
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Freemarker's [capitalize](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_capitalize) built in:

```
class ${name?capitalize}
```

> The string with all words capitalized.